# Custom nested ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to make custom ListView, it should look like this:

Header have to have image and text, then should be listed detail rows.
[image: Custom listview]

My basic datamodel looks

```
public class Workout
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Excercise> Excercises { get; set; }
}
```

Excercises which are first lvl of list:

```
public class Excercise
{
    public string Image{ get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Series> Series { get; set; }
}
```

And then Series, last lvl of lists:

```
public class Series
{
    public uint Repeat { get; set; }

    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

I readed that nested ListViews are not recomended. I want to implement this using Grouping ListView, but how to manage custom header? Basicaly header has just one value, which is key, how to add image and style it?

Any recomendation?

Comment: Keep in mind for the grouped listview to work your `Exercise` should look like this: `public class Exercise : List<Series>` instead of having a list as property (the `ListView` doesn't know otherwise what the sublist is)

Comment: Here is a document for reference.Just customizing-grouping be your want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#customizing-grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the grouped ListView, set the GroupHeaderTemplate property to a custom view.

```
<ListView ...>
  <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid ... />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: To make them expandable/collapsible (like an accordion) can do something like what's described here: https://medium.com/@ishrakland/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview-with-a-sub-listview-mvvm-pattern-27a6bdb671c3